# RoR one-to-many association show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my first Ruby on Rails app I've a one-to-many association

```
class Battle < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rivals, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :rivals, :allow_destroy => true
    attr_accessible :question, :rivals_attributes
end

class Rival < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :battle
    has_attached_file :rival_image, :styles => { :normal => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Let's say a battle has 2 rivals

`<% for rival in @battle.rivals %> <%= rival.name %> <% end %>` displays both rivals that belongs to battle

How do I display first rival and the second one where I need it?

Comment: For one, I'd advise against using `for` loops in Ruby whenever you can. You usually want to use [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) to iterate: `@battle.rivals.each { |rival| do_stuff }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access individual records from a association use:

```
<%= battle.rivals[0].name %>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?

Comment: sorry i thought you wanted just to print them. if you want to access the rivals individually, yo can use  <%= battle.rivals[0].name %>